# Changing UIBarButtonItem font in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code, which used to work before updating my application to Swift3.

```
    let barButtonsAppearanceDictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.tangraText(withSize: 17)!,
                                                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.tangraBlue()]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonsAppearanceDictionary, for: UIControlState())
    let barButtonsDisabledAppearanceDictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.tangraText(withSize: 17)!,
                                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.lightGray]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonsDisabledAppearanceDictionary, for: .disabled)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.tangraBlue(),
                                                        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.tangraText(withSize: 22)!]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.tangraBlue()
```

It's supposed to change the font and color of the navigation bar items, but it's not working anymore. The problem is not with the font, because it appears correctly throughout the app. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works for me in xcode 8. I am able to see the change in the text color for ui barbutton.

Comment: code updated.take a look...

Comment: @NaveenRamanathan weird. Did you try it with a custom font?

Comment: code updated and tested from custom font....

Comment: if you have trouble assigning a custom font let me know...

Comment: @smeshko yes I did. I added a custom ttf file to my project. I used your code and it works

Comment: Let me know the code worked for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: Tested in Xcode 8:

In viewdidLoad:

```
   navigationController?.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
   navigationController?.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
   navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.red
   navigationController?.toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

**Updated:**

AppDelegate:

```
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Villa", size: 25.0)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Output from the code with custom font:

[image]

Comment: As you can see in my code, I am trying to change the appearance of all `UIBarButtonItem`s, so I don't have access to a specific reference.

Comment: It doesn't work, I am using a custom font I have imported into the project. But, as I said, it works perfectly fine everywhere else.

Comment: @smesko just tested and it worked.Might be you have a problem with your custom font.